# Insert into many to many table EF Model First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I'm using ASP.NET MVC4 Model First.

I have two tables `GROUPE` and `TELECHARGEMENT`, and the many to many table which named `AUTORISERTELECHARGEMENT`.

When I want to add in `TELECHARGEMENT` or `GROUPE` I do `context.GROUPE.Add(groupe)` , but I don't know how to add in the many to many relashionship (which contains the primary key of `GROUPE` and `TELECHARGEMENT`).

Comment: share your model class definitions, we'll be able to help you better

Comment: http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/285075model.png

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/05/14/code-first-ef-4-1-building-many-to-many-relationship.aspx

This should work assuming that all the three tables belong to the same database context:

```
GROUPE groupe = new GROUPE { ... };
TELECHARGEMENT telechargement = new TELECHARGEMENT { ... };

AUTORISERTELECHARGEMENT at = new AUTORISERTELECHARGEMENT { groupe.ID_GROUPE, telechargement.ID_TELECHARGEMENT };

context.GROUPE.Add(groupe);
context.TELECHARGEMENT.Add(telechargement );
context.AUTORISERTELECHARGEMENT.Add(at);
```

Comment: the folowing link is to  how to buil o many to many i'm asking howa to insert innto many to many

Comment: @Omar let me know if the updated code works for you.

Comment: that's doesn't work because in asp.net MVC4 when i write AUTORISERTELECHARGEMENT he don't know it.

Comment: That is because the class has not been generated from the model. Try re-generating the class for `AUTORISERTELECHARGEMENT`

Comment: I'm using model first so EF don't generate a class for many to many relashionship, there is a way to add but i forgot it ...